# How i can return specified fields in mongodb find() coursor?

Tags: php, mongodb, field

I try:

```
$fields = array('name'=>true);
find (array(array(), $fields))
```

but it's not working (I get nothing) and I can't see my mistake. Sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

If you use mongodb/mongodb php composer package, you need to specify *projection* option:

```
find([], ['projection' => ['name' => false]])
```

Another example of options:

```
find([], ['limit' => 5, projection' => ['name' => false], ...])
```

Answer (score 1):

The PHP function for `find` does not work like that. Try:

```
find(array(), array('name'=>1))
```

(basically omit the surrounding `array`)

For reference here is the documentation page: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php

Comment: Hi,

i understand but it didnt Work with my Class, any Ideas? Thank you. ;-)

`public function mongoGet($f) {
               $cursor = $this->MoTbl->find($f);
               $k = array();
               $i = 0;

               while($cursor->hasNext()) {
                       $k[$i] = $cursor->getNext();
                       $i++;
               }
               return $k;
       }`

Comment: @lun4tic What do you mean it didn't work? What Class? Can you show some code?

Comment: Sorry, im a little confused today. ;-)

I call the function:
`$m->mongoGet(array(), $fields);`

In this example, i receive all field, not the specified in $fields Array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a specific field in all your records you can do something like this:

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
    foreach( $cursor->fields(array('myField' => true )) as $doc ) {
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($doc);
        echo "</pre>";
```

This would return only 'myFeild' for each document in the collection.

http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.fields.php