# Limit returned fields with PHP MongoClient find() query

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

I am writing a PHP MongoClient Model which accesses mongodb that stores deploy logs with gitlab information, server hosts, and zend restart instructions.  I have a mongo Collection called deployAppConfigs.  Its document structure looks like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54de193790ded22d1cd24c36"),
"app_name" : "ai2_api",
"name" : "AI2 Admin API",
"app_directory" : "path_to_app",
"app_owner" : "www-data:deployers",
"directories" : [],
"vcs" : {
    "type" : "git",
    "name" : "input/ai2-api"
},
"environments" : {
    "development" : {
        ... 
    },
    "qa" : {
        ...
    },
    "staging" : {
        ...
    },
    "production" : {
        ...
},
"actions" : {
    "post_checkout" : [ 
        "composer_install"
    ]
}
```

}

Because there are many documents in this collection, I would like to query the entire collection for only the **"vcs" sub document** and the **"app_name"**.  I am able to execute this command in Robomongo's mongo shell with the following find() query:

```
db.deployAppConfigs.find({}, {"vcs": 1, "app_name": 1})
```

This returns exactly what I want for each document in the collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54de193790ded22d1cd24c36"),
"app_name" : "ai2_api",
"vcs" : {
    "type" : "git",
    "name" : "input/ai2-api"
}
```

}

I am having a problem writing a PHP MongoClient equivalent to that mongo shell command.    I basically want to make a PHP MongoClient version of  this mongo docs example on [Limit Fields to Return from a Query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)
I have tried using an empty array to replace the "{}" in the mongo shell command like this, but it hasn't worked:

```
$query = array (
    array(), 
    array("vcs"=> 1, "app_name"=> 1)
);
```

All the fields share the **vcs.type = "git"** so I tried wrote a query that selects all fields in every document based on that shared value.  It looks like this:

```
$query = array (
   "vcs.type" => "git"
);
```

But this returns the entire document, which is what I want to avoid.

The alternative could be to do a limit projection find() for the first document in the collection and then use the MongoCursor to iterate through the whole collection, but I'd rather not have to do the extra loop if possible.

Essentially, I am asking how to limit the return fields of a find() query to only one subdocument of each document in the entire collection.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit Here's how to use it: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#limit-the-number-of-documents-to-return

Comment: try something like this: `db.deployAppConfigs.find({}, {"vcs": 1, "app_name": 1}).limit(5)`

Comment: Yeah, the mongo docs were what helped me to understand how to limit the query output to certain fields.  I was able to do this in a mongo shell. The problem for me came from having to translate that into PHP MongoClient code.

Comment: Here is correct answer for PHP https://stackoverflow.com/a/46988495/1191125 - use `projection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like I was able to find the solution...  I will solve the question and leave it up in case it ends up being useful to anyone else.

What I ended up having to do was alter my MongoClient custom class find() function, which calls the $collection->find() query, to include a $fields parameter.

Now, the MongoClient->find() query looks like this:

```
$collection->find(
    array("vcs.type" => "git"),
    array("vcs" => 1, "app_name" = 1)
)
```

Found the answer on the MongoClient::cursor::find() : [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php)

Comment: Hmm, sending in an aray didn't work? I use that method a lot. What was the error returned?

Comment: Well, I tried doing essentially this but with an empty array() for the **query** portion of the find() function.  It didn't work because of the way my class function worked... So in actually, I was using the mongoclient find() query correctly, but I was misusing my own code. doh!

Comment: @deusofnull I think you could try `$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor->limit(1);` We used this somewhere as far as I remember.

Comment: @divaka that does not limit the projection